# How to speed up search for many different keywords in a given text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, full-text-search, text-search

I'm looking for the appearance of a couple of key words, stored in a table named "EmailKeywords", within a search string passed with the variable @Searchtext. I accomplished this by the stored procedure written below, which generally works fine. But with many keywords to look for, this takes quite a lot of time because I've to loop through the search text with every keyword.

Does anybody have an idea how to speed up this search? Any hint is welcome.

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE BodyTextLookForKeywords 

    @Searchtext ntext

AS

DECLARE @Found int = 0
DECLARE @Keyword nvarchar(30)

-- Loop through all the listed key words
DECLARE SearchCursor Cursor For SELECT Searchword from EmailKeywords For Read Only

Open SearchCursor
While (0=0) Begin
    Fetch Next
        From SearchCursor
        Into @Keyword
    If (@@Fetch_Status <> 0) 
        Break
    Else
        Begin
            Set @Found = (SELECT PATINDEX('%' + @Keyword+ '%', @Searchtext))
            If @Found > 0 Break
        End
    End
Close SearchCursor
Deallocate SearchCursor

If @Found=0 select 0 as SResult else select 1 as SResult
```

Comment: If performance is a concern avoid cursors. And as far as I can see,  you don't need it at all here.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using cursors if you can do same thing without it.
It is slow, it is an iterative solution. 
In your case you don`t need any cursor here, because you can select directly from table

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM EmailKeyword
WHERE PATINDEX('%' + Searchword + '%', @Searchtext)) > 1)
SELECT 1 as SResult ELSE SELECT 0 as SResult
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce you Stored Procedure's body to this:

```
SELECT @Found = COUNT(*)
FROM EmailKeywords
WHERE PATINDEX('%' + Searchword + '%', @Searchtext) > 0;

SELECT CASE WHEN @Found > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Result;
```